# Unable to find command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Strange things happening, I did `ionic serve` command for running my ionic server, then I receive an option to update to the latest ionic version (3.20.0 => 4.0.0). After the successful update I receiving an error message each time after any `ionic` command:

```
[ERROR] Unable to find command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
        C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic platform add android
```

What's happening? I tried to reinstall node.js, then tried to install 7.0.0, then tried to reinstall ionic to previous version but nothing helps me. Npm and node commands works well. Why it stopped works even with the previous version?

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, rolling back didn't fix it. I uninstalled and re-installed ionic and now it works again.

npm uninstall -g ionic

npm install -g ionic